# Add horizontal arrows to hscroll when the content is off the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using chakra-ui and I have a horizontal tablist that allows overflow, like so:

```
<Tabs
  index={index}
  align="center">
  <Box overflow="auto" style={webkit}>
    <TabList
     position="relative"
     w="max-content">
       {tabs.map((tab) => (
         <Box id={tab.id} key={tab.id}>
           <Tab
            as={Link}
            href={tab.href}>
              {tab.name}
            </Tab>
         </Box>
       ))}
   </TabList>
</Tabs>
```

However, when the rightmost tab goes off the screen, it is simply cut off, and if it is cut off between two tabs it is not obvious that there are more tabs that are off the screen. What I would like to do is make arrows that show up on the sides if there is more content. I am imagining the edge of the hscroll fading to reveal an arrow, and if the user clicks the arrow it scrolls over. Then when they scroll all the way to the side, the arrow disappears. I imagine that this must exist somewhere, but I have been unable to find it. Could anyone point me in the right direction or give me tips on how to achieve this?